# Can we get the user's phone number from twitter sdk using fabric

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, twitter-fabric

Integrated the twitter in to native app using fabric. got how to fetch user's email but not getting can we get the phone number also and user's location also.Please guide for above.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it doesn't look like you can get Telephone number from the Twitter API

See https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup for a full set of parameters and some examples of what can be retrieved.